# How can I hide the touch-screen joysticks in the main menu?

Tags: unity

I am a Unity beginner trying to make an app/game. How do I hide the touch-screen joysticks from showing on-screen in the main menu before the game/app actually starts?

Comment: Can you add some more details about how you implemented your touch-screen joystick control?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SetActive(false)?
Use it while opening main menu. When loading the game scene, use SetActive(true).

Warning - you have to store a reference to the UI element to set it back to active.
At least that's how it was when I last used Unity.